# Regarding transparency feature in Gnome desktop environment in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, gnome-terminal, transparency

I am not able to make the terminal's background transparent, even though have tried the option of going to EDIT->PROFILE PREFERENCES -> BACKGROUND -> TRANSPARENT BACKGROUND.

Pls help me out.

Comment: Are you using a PPA? What's the version of terminal: `gnome-terminal --version`?

Answer (score 0):

Which desktop environment are you using?  When you log in, you can select them by clicking the icon to the right of your username.

If I log in under Ubuntu(Default), I can get it transparent.  If I switch to GNOME, I can't.  However, if I log in under GNOME classic,(can't figure out how to open a terminal with that one yet).

Under GNOME flashback, I get intermediate behavior.
It appears that "transparent background" means something different in flashback.  If you move the terminal shell around on the screen, you'll see that the the terminal is transparent to the desktop background.

This is especially obvious if you set your desktop to a wallpaper.  Howeve, the terminal shell still blocks out the icons that you may have put on your desktop, as well as other windows open.

Metacity has the same behavior as flashback.

So, it's possible that if you want a transparent shell, you may be restricted in your desktop background.